# non-declarative markup language

Tags: markup, declarative

[Wikipedia states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming#Domain-specific_languages):

> Many markup languages such as HTML, MXML, XAML, XSLT or other
>   user-interface markup languages are often declarative. HTML, for
>   example, only describes what should appear on a webpage - it does not
>   specify the possible interactions with that webpage.

Which implies that there are markup languages which are *non-declarative* (use of the word **often**). I suspect this is not the case - Are there any non-declarative markup languages?

Comment: I think (and could very well be wrong) that referring to alternative language constructs as "non-declarative" would be like referring to someone who isn't an alcoholic as a "non-alcoholic". What Im trying to say is that other constructs fall into completely different paradigms of programming and can't be contrasted against declarative languages. An example would be imperative programming. I guess "often" was just a poor choice of words by that author ;)

Comment: @Jbird but there are no imperative markup languages. The concept doesn't really make sense? This might have to go to the Wikipedia talk page.

Comment: I'd hazard an opinion that how best to define "declarative" varies by context. The separation of style from semantics is one way that HTML is more "declarative" than troff or CFML, though macro packages can be used to separate them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CFML (Coldfusion Markup Language) and o:XML(object-oriented XML) are two non-declarative markup languages:

> CFML tags are essentially much more powerful versions of Java Tag Libraries, and with CFML's ECMAScript-like syntax you'll feel right at home.
>
> o:XML is a complete object oriented programming language, with features including polymorphism, function overloading, exception handling, threads and more. The syntax is fully compliant XML. With o:XML, object-oriented paradigms can be leveraged to the maximum, while data and code remains in a standard format. With o:XML there is no 'impedance mismatch' when developing XML web-applications, tools and systems.

**References**

- [o:XML - object-oriented XML](http://www.o-xml.org/)
- [Schema for Object-Oriented XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-SOX/)
- [Introducing o:XML](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/07/21/oxml.html)
- [Why CFML? - Open CFML Foundation](http://www.opencfmlfoundation.org/why-cfml/)
- [Object Oriented Programming And ColdFusion - What's The Point?](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1385-object-oriented-programming-and-coldfusion---what-s-the-point.htm)